# why does this python regex return no match?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
>>> match = re.search(r'\d', 'ca\d')
>>> type(match) 
<type 'NoneType'>
```

From my understanding 'r' means don't do any special processing with blackslashes and just return the raw string.

Also, why do i get the output below:

```
>>> match = re.search(r'\a', 'ca\a')
>>> match.group()
'\x07'
```

Answer (score 4):

Because your input string has no digit. `\d` means `capture a digit`.

If you want to capture a literal `\d`, you should use `\\d` pattern.

See [example here](https://regex101.com/r/aK4fA4/1).

This program

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\\d')
test_str = u"ca\d"
print re.search(p, test_str).group(0)
```

Will output `\d`.

As for `r''`, please check this [re documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular
>   expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in
>   a string literal prefixed with 'r'. So r"\n" is a two-character string
>   containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string
>   containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python
>   code using this raw string notation.

It does not mean it does not process slashes anyhow, this just lets you use a single slash instead of a doubled one. The slash is meaningful before `d` in a regular expression.

And as for `\a`, there is no such a regex metacharacter, so `\` is treated as a literal.

Answer (score 1):

And in addition to stribizhev's comment, probably the 'r' (raw string indicator) is making you confused. That is used to avoid escaping. Escaping is a form of allowing writing in the code special (unprintable) characters like:
TAB - ASCII 9 - "\t"
CR - ASCII 13 - "\r" (Unix Enter)

But there's no special char that has the code "\d", so placing an r in front of it makes no difference, so the string will still be "\d" (2 chars) that in regex, matches over a digit.